# ASN1_INT what it really is?

Tags: delphi, indy, asn.1

Well, this is my code uses ASN1Util:

```
SNMP.Query.MIBAdd('1.3.6.1.4.1.6247.24.1.2.2.10.0',Value,ASN1_INT);
```

*Value* type must be **string** 
But on Mib browser only **integer** is acceptable.

So if I'm not mistaken **ASN1_Int** means whatever I put in "value", it's always understood as an integer?

Comment: I dont know, but you should add indy to the tags. You might get more help.

Comment: Also after looking at a quick example, it seems you are correct assumeing your string is an number.  `IdSNMP1->Query->MIBAdd("1.3.6.1.4.1.38783.3.3.0","1",ASN1_INT);`

Comment: Yes, you would provide `MibAdd()` with the string representation of the integer value.  `TIdSNMP` will convert to a true integer internally via `StrToInt()` when encoding the SNMP request.